# How can access json in dart in following response

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying access redirect url in following json

tried with           `print('on launch ${message['data'].redirect_url}');`

but getting a runtime error.

this was response getting inside message['data']  =>

```
  I/flutter (23626): on launch {type: api-testing, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, redirect_url: https://google.com}
```

How can I access only redirect  URL as a string?

Comment: What's the datatype of `message['data']`?

Comment: onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('on launch ${message['data']}');
          print('*************1');
          print('on message $message');
        },

Comment: look above the code you will get an idea

Comment: Could you post output of `print(message['data'].runtimeType);`?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data as a key in `Map` here you are wrong. You are parsing redirectUrl key so you have to use `redirectUrl` as a key in map I mean to say:

```
Message['redirecturl']
```